# laravel | query returns a collection of all records even when using find

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to fetch trashed records in relationships while eager loading but I get returned all the records instead of the one with respective `id`

Here is the query in question,

```
$collections = User::findOrFail($id->id)->with(['collection' => function ($query) {
$query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->with(['loan' => function ($query) {
$query->withTrashed()->with(['customer' => function ($query) {
$query->withTrashed();
}]);
}]);
}])->get();
```

This gives me a result like

```
Collection {#257 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => User {#265 ▶}
    1 => User {#266 ▶}
  ]
}
```

whats going wrong here?

Comment: try to make `with(...)` before` findorfail`

Comment: what is $id? Is it actual id or is it an object?

Comment: @Tim $id is an object $id->id refers to the actual id

Comment: I am not an expert but can you try fetching with first() instead of get()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the `with` before the `findOrFail`, however the 2 are not really compatible things. Do the following instead:

```
$collections = User::with(['collection' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->with(['loan' => function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed()->with(['customer' => function ($query) {
                    $query->withTrashed();
                }]);
        }]);
}])->where("id",$id->id)->firstOrFail();
```